# UINavigation controller with different orientations

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to create a UINavigationController, with a Master View Controller, and a Detail View Controller.

The Master View Controller can be rotated in Portrait and LandscapeRight, while the detail View Controller can only be only be viewed in LandscapeRight (the Detail shows a movie).

What's the best way of setting this up?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding the following lines of code

On your Master View Controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

     return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

and on your Detail View Controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

     return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: oh lordy, if only it were that simple.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 7, the method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

has been deprecated. You can however use

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

to simply return a yes/no.

and then you can tell the viewcontroller which orientations are acceptable in

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```